# Eclipse - an error ocurred while executing doInBackground()

Tags: android, eclipse, background

I have a simple application. Just to connect with a Server and get the result. But when I run it I get this message:

```
04-13 11:55:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(16005): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-13 11:55:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(16005): Process: com.tumta.consultatempo, PID: 16005
04-13 11:55:41.935: E/AndroidRuntime(16005): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

My Class:

```
package com.tumta.consultatempo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class ConsultaSituacaoTempo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private ConsultaConcluidaListener listener;

    private static final String URL_STRING = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Sorocaba,sp";

    public ConsultaSituacaoTempo(ConsultaConcluidaListener listener){
        this.listener = listener;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            String resultado = ConsultaServidor();
            return InterpretaResultado(resultado);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String InterpretaResultado(String resultado) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(resultado);
        JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("weather");
        JSONObject jsonWaether = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        int id = jsonWaether.getInt("id");
        String descricao = jsonWaether.getString("description");

        return "Situacao do tempo em Sorocaba: " + id + " - " + descricao;
    }


    private String ConsultaServidor() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            conn.getResponseCode();

            is = conn.getInputStream();

            Reader reader = null;
            reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            char[] buffer = new char[2048];
            reader.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer);
        }finally{
            if(is != null){
                is.close();
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        listener.onConsultaConcluida(result);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    public interface ConsultaConcluidaListener{
        void onConsultaConcluida(String situacaoTempo);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why I am getting this exception. Does anyone knows what is wrong?
Thank`s.

*****EDIT*****
Here`s my cmplete LogCat:

```
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547): Process: com.tumta.consultatempo, PID: 16547
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:373)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.tumta.consultatempo.ConsultaSituacaoTempo.ConsultaServidor(ConsultaSituacaoTempo.java:63)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.tumta.consultatempo.ConsultaSituacaoTempo.doInBackground(ConsultaSituacaoTempo.java:30)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at com.tumta.consultatempo.ConsultaSituacaoTempo.doInBackground(ConsultaSituacaoTempo.java:1)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    ... 4 more
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547): Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(Native Method)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:438)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    ... 18 more
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547): Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
04-13 15:41:22.149: E/AndroidRuntime(16547):    ... 21 more
```

Comment: Can you provide complete Logcat error. This error usually caused by [NullPointerException](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/NullPointerException.html). Unless you provide complete error log we cant help

Comment: Here it is! @SaiPhani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Add the [INTERNET](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: What happened was that I had this permission. But it had a typing mistake.. hahaha Thanks!!